# Neither deployment directory nor war file specified for Axis2 web application

Tags: java, apache-axis

I tried everything in this [tutorial](http://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/java-web-service-with-apache-axis2-in-netbeans/), But when it cam time to deploy the web service i got this error.
[image]

As you can see the configuration it says doesn't exist actually exists. I searched Google but all I could find was instances where people had the same problem, but the resolution was never posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
I found solution regarding mentioned problem. It seems Netbeans 7.4+ is not creating axis2 config file for deployment. You can do it manually.

here is the guide how to do it in French:
http://vincent-lecomte.blogspot.be/2014/10/java-probleme-config-axis2-et-netbeans.html


Below is my config for Netbeans 8.0:

1. Go to directory C:\Users\[Curr user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules
2. Create folder "websvc"
3. In the folder "websvc" create file "axis2.properties"
4. In the file "axis2.properties" paste below text:

    AXIS_DEPLOY=D:\\Tomcat\\webapps\\axis2    //change to the directory where axis2 is installed
    AXIS_URL=http://[yourhost]:8080/axis2
    TOMCAT_MANAGER_USER=user
    TOMCAT_MANAGER_PASSWORD=password

Hope this helps.
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi follow these steps to resolve the issue.

Step 1: Download axis2 plugin file “org-netbeans-modules-websvc-axis2.nbm” from Internet.Install plugin in netbeans and restart the netbeans.

Step 2: Browse location of .nbm file and click on install and then restart the netbeans.

The major problem after the creation of project is deployment in tomcat server.
While we are doing the deployment it shows the following.

"Neither deployment directory nor war file specified for Axis2 web application (Axis2 environment).
Please, specify the axis2.war or axis2 deployment directory location in

Tools -> Options -> Axis2 -> Deployment panel."

To resolve the above issue please follow the steps.

•   Go to the following folder: 
    UserProfile\ AppData \ Roaming \ IDE \ 7.4 \ config \Preferences \ org \ netbeans \ modules.

•   Create a subfolder "websvc".

•   Create a "axis2.properties" file.

•   Add the following properties (double slashes to the deployment directory):

AXIS_DEPLOY=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\axis2.war

AXIS_URL=http://localhost:8090/axis2

TOMCAT_MANAGER_PASSWORD=root

TOMCAT_MANAGER_USER=root

The final file path will be(For example):
C:\Users\BalaSubrahmanyam\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\websvc\ axis2.properties

Save the file and then restart the netbeans again and buid the project.

The customized axis2 war is now deployed in tomcat server.